# Why there is no mc0 folder in /sys/devices/system/edac/mc

Tags: linux, drivers, memory

I tested RHEL 8.1, I can see `mc0` in `/sys/devices/system/edac/mc`.

I tested Debian 9.9 on the same machine, there is no `mc0` folder in `/sys/devices/system/edac/mc`.

Is that because some drivers didn't load? Which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will happen if the relevant driver doesn’t load, presumably because it’s included in the RHEL 8 kernel (based on 4.18) but not in the Debian 9 kernel (based on 4.9). If you test Debian 10 (whose kernel is based on 4.19) instead, you should find the EDAC is handled correctly.

Looking at `/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/mc_name` on RHEL will tell you what the memory controller name is, which will help determine what driver is necessary.